# Failed to mount early API filesystems

Tags: 20.04, grub2, initramfs, fsck

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my system, but I'm unable to load it. I'm getting the following error while loading.
Output of `fsck /dev/sda2 -y` and `exit` is attached.

[image]

Comment: Disk is dead or dying. Have you been shutting it down with the power switch instead of a proper shutdown?

Comment: I had pending updates , once i updated after some time suddenly it started throwing some logs in terminal and it was freezed for long time then I had force shutdown

Comment: Shutting down by the power switch can mess up the file system but if fsck did not fix it like I said the disk may be bad.

Comment: @David any solution to fix bad sectors in HDD

Comment: Sorry no a bad disk is a dead disk.